# intersection between plane and sphere raytracing

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, raytracing

Im trying to find the intersection point between a line and a sphere for my raytracer. What i have so far works, but the z-intersection point of return 15, which is not good for a sphere with a radius of 1. What am i doing wrong. `new_origin` is the intersection point of the ray with the sphere. `new_direction` is the normal at that intersection. Apparently `new_origin` is calculated wrong.

`origin` and `direction` are the origin and the direction of the ray(line).

my code:

```
bool Sphere::intersection(const glm::vec3 &origin, const glm::vec3 &direction, glm::vec3 &new_origin, glm::vec3 &new_direction)
{
    //
    // See this for explantion of the formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection
    //
    glm::vec3 trans_origin = origin - this->origin;
    float a = glm::dot(direction, direction);
    float b = 2 * glm::dot(trans_origin, direction);
    float c = glm::dot(trans_origin, trans_origin) - this->radius * this->radius;

    float discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (discriminant < 0.f) return false;

    float depth = (-b + sqrtf(discriminant)) / 2 * a;
    float t = (-b - sqrtf(discriminant)) / 2 * a;

    if(t < depth) {
        depth = t;
    }
    new_origin = origin + depth * direction;
    new_direction = glm::normalize(trans_origin + depth * direction);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `(-b + sqrtf(discriminant)) / 2 * a` is incorrect. Should be `(-b + sqrtf(discriminant)) / (2 * a)`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues (operator precendence) was already pointed out by [3Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135769/3dave) in their comment

> `(-b + sqrtf(discriminant)) / 2 * a` is incorrect. Should be `(-b + sqrtf(discriminant)) / (2 * a)`.

The other comes later, when the *lesser* intersection is chosen.

```
if (t < depth) {
    depth = t;
}
```

Given that a ray has a point of origin and a direction, even if you find two points of intersection, the sphere could be in the opposite direction or the orign of the ray could be inside the sphere.

What you need is the **lower positive** solution.

Another possible issue is about `new_direction`, but it's not entirely clear to me which "normal" are you considering.